# Set ons-switch with predifined values from Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I cannot seem to get the correct way to set the 'checked' attribute in ons-switch. This is so that I can setup user configurations page with pre-checked select boxes.

The Docs:
This is a checked switch but how do I set this using a variable in an angular controller?

For example, if ons-switch has a syntax like 
 
I could have done:

I cannot seem to set attribute "checked" with no value in angular, as needed in the docs. I'm also unable to access the variable since it is part of an array of configurations.

Code Example:

controller:

```
var categInfo = [{Interest:'Classic', isChecked:true}, {Interest:'New', isChecked:false}];
```

html:

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="interest in categInfo" >
    <span style="color: #666">{{interest.Interest}}</span>
    <ons-switch modifier="list-item" var="{{interest.Interest}}" checked="{{interest.isChecked}}"></ons-switch>
</ons-list-item>
```

So what I want is that the html should show buttons that are checked/unchecked depending on interest.isChecked is true or false.

Comment: Have you tried using 'ng-model' and bind the switch with it? Do you have some code?

Comment: Hi Andi, I have updated the post with simplified code to explain what I am trying... The problem is that checked=true and checked=false in the html both show a button that is checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to bind the switch with `ng-model`, this will allow you to manage the `ons-switch` behavior directly from the controller. Setting the variable `true` or `false`, inside the controller, will automatically change the value of the state of the switch, same thing if you change the state from the switch (AngularJS binding).

If you want to check the status of the switch, you need to check the model value.

Here is a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/JdEPKW?editors=101). and the relative code.

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <ons-switch ng-model="switch"></ons-switch>
  <ons-button ng-click="changeSwitch()">Change switch status</ons-button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```js
ons.bootstrap()

.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.changeSwitch = function() {
    $scope.switch = !$scope.switch;
    if($scope.switch)
      alert('checked');
    else
      alert('unchecked');
  };
});
```

**EDIT: SWITCH ARRAY EXAMPLE**

Due to an Onsen UI bug about the initialization of the `ons-switch` element, I suggest you to use the following code to implement your switch.

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch__input" checked>
    <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
</label>
```

The appearance will be the same as the `ons-switch` element. This bug will be fixed in Onsen UI 1.4 release, so you can start using again the switch element after its release.

For what concerns the behavior of an array of switches, it's analog of the single switch. You still need to use 'ng-model' to bind the status of the switch. You are using `ng-repeat` to display the switch elements so, by using `ng-model="item.isChecked"`, every element will be binded with the relative `isChecked` value inside the array. Here you can find a working [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/BNWxXJ), and this is the relative code:

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h2>What I am trying</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="item in categInfo"> 
  <div>This button should be {{item.isChecked}}</div>      
    <label class="switch">
      <input ng-model="item.isChecked" type="checkbox" class="switch__input" checked>
      <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```js
ons.bootstrap()

.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  //Need to go through the array and set as checked or not
  $scope.categInfo = [{Interest:'Classic', isChecked:true}, {Interest:'New', isChecked:false}]; 
});
```

Comment: Hey Andi, thanks thats  really close to what I need but how do I work with this if the number of switches depends on the array: Example based on your codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVymEM

Comment: @Gibbet I have prepared an example, but I'm waiting to post it because I found something very weird, please patient a little bit more ;)

Comment: @Gibbet I answered your question. If it helped you, please consider to upvote and mark as best answer my answer. It will help future users, with the same problem, to find the solution easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andi! Had no idea about these onsen components, had to google to find them...